# UDP stream capture and replay

Tags: udp

I am capturing audio from a radio device to my android using tcpdump.
How can I take this cap file and replay the UDP stream within it? As I want to replay the audio I got from the radio.

Answer (score 0):

UDP usually uses dynamical port numbers on client side, therefore just replaying will not work.

Note: The following bases on the assumption that the audio stream is transmitted using a common standardized protocol and is not encrypted or otherwise protected like it is on streaming apps like Spotify, Dezzer, ...

Instead you need to extract the UDP data stream from the created packet dump (usually in pcap file format). See for example [this question](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/7092).

Then you need a streaming server software that allows to stream the data you have extracted. The server can run on a PC that can be accessed via network from your Android phone or on the Android device itself. I assume that the client software on your Android device allows to specify the audio streaming server.

Comment: I managed extracting the packets to pcap file using tcpdump. Now I have the file on my Android device, can you recommend an app that will be able to replay it and recreate the audio?

Comment: @Dean You also need to find out what data format is used, analyze the extracted data if it can be directly played within e.g. VLC on a PC. Regarding the server I can't  make any recommendations, sorry.